# Flutter Firebase Analytics Not Logging Event

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-analytics

Hi I just added Firebase Analytics to my flutter application. I have added two functions.

1. Set Current Screen.
2. Log Event.

Set Current Screen is working fine. I am able to see the screens in Analytics/Events/Screen_views. So the Firebase configurations must have been correct.

Log Event is not showing any Error, but it is not shown anywhere in the firebase dashboard. I have an Event "Home page Loaded". This is my code.

I have waited for more than 48 hours now.

await analytics.logEvent(
    name: eventName,
    parameters: {
    },
  );

Has anyone implemented Firebase Analytics in Flutter Application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot have spaces in the event or parameter name, only in values, change `Home page Loaded` to `Home_page_Loaded` (personally I like to see all lowercase).

From the docs:

> The name of the event. Should contain 1 to 40 alphanumeric characters or underscores. The name must start with an alphabetic character. Some event names are reserved

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#logEvent(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)

Comment: The link you have added that is very helpful for me Thanks.